# Getting an Id value using a class value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several divs that I want to work with dynamically.

```
<div class="parent-19" id="123">  </div>
<div class="parent-19" id="124">  </div>
<div class="parent-19" id="125">  </div>
```

Now, I want to iterate through them like:

```
 $('.parent-19').each(function () {
           //Want to load the id into a variable
    });
```

How can I load the id value (e.g. 123) into a variable?

```
var Id = $(this).???
```

Comment: Ids aren't allowed to start with a number.

Comment: @kgiannakakis: That's true for HTML4, but HTML5 is more relaxed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap `this` with the jQuery object to get the id. Simply do:

```
var id = this.id;
```

To get an array of ids:

```
var ids = $('.parent-19').map(function () {
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: and this returns an array if there are more than one?

Comment: @cinqoTimo, no, you have to explicitly create an array and put values into it to do that. I'll update my answer with an example, using a handy jQuery shortcut, `map`, which does that for you based on return values.